# C# simple console application to compute GPA (Help)

Tags: c#, console, calculator

I am a rookie programmer who is still new to C#. I am wondering why won't my application compute the user's GPA correctly. The code looks fine to me. I appreciate if there are tips to improve my code as well.

For example, if a user enter grade A for module #1 with credit unit 5, and grade B for module #2 with credit unit 2, after pressing 0 to exit, GPA computed will be 0.0

Basically the user can compute his GPA for any number of modules he want. The algorithm for the module and credit unit seems ok, but I still dont get why won't the GPA be correct.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("\n********************************************\n");
        int creditUnit = 0;
        int totalCreditUnit = 0;

        char grade = ' ';
        int gradePoint = 0;
        int total = 0;

        int counter = 0;
        double GPA = 0;

        do
        {
            Console.Write("Enter grade for module #{0} (press 0 to exit): ", counter += 1);
            // write some code to prevent user from entering more than 10
            char userInput = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (userInput == '0')
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                grade = userInput; //assigns value for userInput into gradePoint
                Console.Write("Enter credit unit(s) for grade: ");
                totalCreditUnit = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (grade)
                {
                    case 'A': gradePoint += 4;
                        break;
                    case 'B': gradePoint += 3;
                        break;
                    case 'C': gradePoint += 2;
                        break;
                    case 'D': gradePoint += 1;
                        break;
                }
                total += creditUnit * gradePoint;
                totalCreditUnit += creditUnit;
            }

        } while (grade != 0);

        GPA = total  / totalCreditUnit;
        Console.Write("Your GPA this semester is {0:F2}", GPA);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
totalCreditUnit = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

That should be `creditUnit` not `totalCreditUnit`. Later you are doing:

```
        total += creditUnit * gradePoint;
        totalCreditUnit += creditUnit;
```

`creditUnit` is always zero so you are never adding anything to total and always end up dividing zero by `totalCreditUnit`.

Now would be a great time to learn to use the debugger in Visual Studio. You would have found this pretty quickly if you had inspected the values of `total` and `totalCreditUnit` yourself. I would also cast them to double when performing the division operation.

Comment: Thanks. Also, I realized that an when you divide an int over an int and assign it to a double, the result will be cast into an int, causing me the incorrect values.